# How to pass "EVERYTHING" as an argument to a WHERE clause in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause

I have written a function which returns an Bigquery SQL query using the parameters passed to the function. The query includes `WHERE movie_genre IN ({supported_genres})`.

I want to be able to pass `romance, comedy, action` as an value for supported_genres which I can do. And I also want to be able to use the same function to fetch another dataset which doesn't include any WHERE condition.

Ideally, I expect to pass something like "ANYTHING" to supported_genres.
How can I achieve this (a WHERE clause not having any effect) in Bigquery?

Comment: something like `WHERE {supported_genres} = '' OR movie_genre IN ({supported_genres})`?

Comment: Given `movie_genre IN ANYTHING` is always true, why not omit that clause?

Comment: I want to keep that clause in the query so that I can use it when required. @Kei

Comment: Ah okay. In that case, try Nick's suggestion. If you have other clauses in your WHERE condition, be sure to wrap the clause Nick suggested in parentheses to make sure it doesn't affect the others

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> Option #1

```
#standardSQL
WITH supported_genres AS (
  SELECT 'romance' movie_genre UNION ALL
  SELECT 'comedy' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'action' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ANYTHING'
)
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM supported_genres 
  WHERE movie_genre = t.movie_genre OR movie_genre = 'ANYTHING'
)
```

In above, without changing your WHERE clause - you just control output by having `'ANYTHING'` in `supported_genres` CTE if you need to output all genres. Or, you can remove `'ANYTHING'` from `supported_genres` CTE if you need to output only specific genres

> Option #2

Another option would be as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE movie_genre IN UNNEST(IF(TRUE, ['romance', 'comedy', 'action'], [movie_genre]))
```

In above query you can control to select supported genres only - by providing `true` in `UNNEST(IF(TRUE, ['romance', 'comedy', 'action'], [movie_genre]))`.

Or you can pass `false` as in `UNNEST(IF(FALSE, ['romance', 'comedy', 'action'], [movie_genre]))`

Note: there are really quite a number of options here and it is just matter of your preferences and particular use case. Hope you can find yours based on above two examples